# Impede the database writing with a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I wrote this trigger to impede the database's writing

```
create or replace trigger spese_autorizzate_trg
before insert or update on spese
for each row
declare 
    boolean integer := 0;
    voceSpesa tipospesa.descrizione%TYPE := NULL;

begin  
    select
        descrizione into voceSpesa
    from
        tipospesa
    where
        id = :new.tipospesa
        and approvazione = 'n';


    if voceSPesa is NULL then  
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'La spesa '||voceSpesa||' non è rimborsabile');
    end if;
end;
```

If the value of tipospesa is 4 or 5, the writing should be impeded 
but when I insert a row like this

```
insert into spese(id, importo, tipospesa, data) values (4, 20, 3, TO_DATE('15-jul-18', 'DD-MON-RR'))
```

I have this error

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "PARLAMENTO2018.SPESE_AUTORIZZATE_TRG", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger
'PARLAMENTO2018.SPESE_AUTORIZZATE_TRG'
01403. 00000 -  "no data found"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

and the writing isn't done. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it seems that you'd have to handle `NO_DATA_FOUND`, instead of handling possibility that `DESCRIZIONE` is `NULL`. Something like this:

```
create or replace trigger spese_autorizzate_trg
  before insert or update on spese
  for each row
declare 
    --  boolean integer := 0;              -- Uh, no! Boolean is name of PL/SQL datatype; 
                                           -- don't use it as name of a variable
                                           -- Besides, it is never used in your code.
    voceSpesa tipospesa.descrizione%TYPE;  -- No need to set it to NULL explicitly; 
                                           -- it is NULL anyway

begin  
  select descrizione 
    into voceSpesa
    from tipospesa
    where id = :new.tipospesa
      and approvazione = 'n';

exception
  when no_data_found then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'La spesa '||voceSpesa||' non è rimborsabile');

  when too_many_rows then
    -- what then? Do you know? Can that select return more than a single row? If so,
    -- you should handle it
    null;
end;
```

True, you could save some typing by using `select max(descrizione) ...`, but that's kind of tricky. If someone else *inherits* your code, will they know that you used MAX to avoid `NO_DATA_FOUND`, or whether you intentionally meant to select the largest value of that column? Therefore, I'd say that it is better to actually *handle* exceptions you expect and avoid any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an `INTO` clause will fail if no rows are returned from the table, raising `no_data_found`

`MAX` or `MIN` may be used to give you a `NULL` in case there were no rows.

```
select
    MAX(descrizione) into voceSpesa
from
    tipospesa
where
    id = :new.tipospesa
    and approvazione = 'n';
```

Do remember that this will also have null in cases where the column `descrizione` itself is `null`. But, it purely depends on your requirement how you would like to handle that situation if it ever occurs.

Comment: I didn't know who MAX function could can be used in this mode. Thansk